# Android layout design - How to get the screen height in xml(layouts)

Tags: android, android-layout

I have to design the screen.I want to put the footer bar below the list.
See here:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/main"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/wallpaper">

<!-- Header -->
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/header"
    android:background="#0099CC"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/routeCode"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Code"
        android:width="100dip"
        android:height="30dip"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/routeName"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name"
        android:width="150dip"
        android:height="30dip"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/outlets"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Outlets"
        android:width="60dip"
        android:height="30dip"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    />
</LinearLayout>

<!-- List Divider -->
<View android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />

    <!-- ListView (grid_items) -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                                        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
                  android:layout_height="405dp"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        </ListView>

        <TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                  android:gravity="center_vertical"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                  android:layout_marginTop="25dp" 
                  android:text="No Sales Routes Define By Admin" />
    </LinearLayout>

     <!-- Footer -->
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/header"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">

        <Button android:text="Exit" 
                android:id="@+id/button1" 
                android:background="#0099FF"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:onClick="onExitAction">
        </Button>

        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:text="Next" 
                android:background="#0099FF"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/button2" 
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:onClick="onNextAction">
       </Button>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Problem is if there no data for list or few rows are avilable, then footerbar will come up.How to fix that thing.I want to fixed in below part.I won't to come up....

When I add this code `android:layout_weight="1"` it coming like this :
 [image]

This is my Tab xml part;

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

   <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:tabStripEnabled="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
   </TabHost>
```

I want that bar above the tab..

Please help me..

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/main"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/icon">

<!-- Header -->
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/header"
    android:background="#0099CC"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/routeCode"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Code"
        android:width="100dip"
        android:height="30dip"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/routeName"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name"
        android:width="150dip"
        android:height="30dip"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/outlets"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Outlets"
        android:width="60dip"
        android:height="30dip"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    />
</LinearLayout>

<!-- List Divider -->
<View
    android:id="@+id/myView" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:background="?android:attr/listDivider"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header" />

    <!-- ListView (grid_items) -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout"
                  android:layout_below="@+id/myView"    
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        </ListView>

        <TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                  android:gravity="center_vertical"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                  android:layout_marginTop="25dp" 
                  android:text="No Sales Routes Define By Admin" />
    </LinearLayout>

     <!-- Footer -->
    <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"  
       android:id="@+id/MyRelative"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">

        <Button android:text="Exit" 
                android:id="@+id/button1" 
                android:background="#0099FF"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:onClick="onExitAction">
        </Button>

        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:text="Next" 
                android:background="#0099FF"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/button2" 
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:onClick="onNextAction">
       </Button>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have change <TabWidget android:layout_weight="0" > according to ur code

Answer (score 2):

You should use weights for the `LinearLayout` with the `ListView` inside:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="0dip"
              android:layout_weight="1" >
```

**EDIT**:
Use the following layout for the "Tabs":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fadingEdge="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:tabStripEnabled="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Comment: I thanks.Its working... but I have issue..I have tab in the bottom.above the tab I want to set the footer bar.... Currently its going to behind the tab & bottom of screen..

Comment: How do you add this tab? If it's in xml, could you please add this code to the question. Unfortunately I can't understand the problem clearly using this description.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/main"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:background="#ff0000">

<!-- Header -->
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/header"
    android:background="#0099CC"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/routeCode"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Code"
        android:width="100dip"
        android:height="30dip"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/routeName"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name"
        android:width="150dip"
        android:height="30dip"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/outlets"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:text="Outlets"
        android:width="60dip"
        android:height="30dip"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    />
</LinearLayout>

<!-- List Divider -->
<View android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />

    <!-- ListView (grid_items) -->
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="0dip"
                  android:layout_weight="1.0" >

        <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        </ListView>

        <TextView android:id="@id/android:empty"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                  android:gravity="center_vertical"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                  android:layout_marginTop="25dp" 
                  android:text="No Sales Routes Define By Admin" />
    </LinearLayout>

     <!-- Footer -->
    <RelativeLayout  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button android:text="Exit" 
                android:id="@+id/button1" 
                android:background="#0099FF"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:onClick="onExitAction"/>

        <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:text="Next" 
                android:background="#0099FF"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:id="@+id/button2"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
                android:onClick="onNextAction"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd be tempted to make your master container in to a `RelativeLayout` and then set `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` on your footer container